# Disfunctional API call with JS

Tags: javascript

I have a noob question about an API call in JS. I don't have any error in the console, the element is created but data is not displayed.

Here is my code:

```js
var cryptoElt = document.getElementById("crypto");
ajaxGet("https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/bitcoin/", function (reponse) {
    var bitcoin = JSON.parse(reponse);
    var idElt = document.createElement("p");
    idElt.textContent = bitcoin.id;
    cryptoElt.appendChild(idElt);
});
```

no error in console
here is P in page source code
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0aRcC.png)

But no data displayed...

I don't get it

Comment: If you paste `console.log(reponse)` into the callback function, what do you get back?

Comment: What is ajaxGet? Maybe you should give us that method so we can run your code.

Comment: I do get an error. If you are using a library, please also import it to stackoverflow, if it has an cdn, else I would remove that snippet, as it is pretty much useless

Answer (score 0):

The API you are using returns an *array*, not an *object*.

```
idElt.textContent = bitcoin[0].id;
```